# Wrapping divs in to wrapper div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Like the title says, I would need to wrap some divs inside of of div. Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="something1 message">
<span class="message-text">This is notification 1</span>
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="something2 message">
<span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
<span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
<span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div id="content-wrapper" class"message">
<span class="message-text">Anotherexample</span>
<span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Now what I would like to the output to be:

```
 <div class="something1 message">
<div class="message-text-wrapper">
    <span class="message-text">This is notification 1</span>
</div>
    <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="something2 message">
<div class="message-text-wrapper">
    <span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
    <span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
    <span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
</div>
    <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="content-wrapper" class"message">
<div class="message-text-wrapper">
    <span class="message-text">Anotherexample</span>
    <span class="message-text">There can be multiple texts like this</span>
</div>
    <input type="text" />
    </div>
```

Basically that all "message-text" spans that are inside of invidual message div would we wrapped inside message-text-wrappe div.

Hopefully you understant.

Comment: Do you intend to wrap `single span` or `multiple spans`, it seems you got both mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? It's untested. But something like this...

```
$('.message-text:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
 $(this).nextAll('.message-text').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='message-text-wrapper'></div>");
}):
```

Comment: Almost works. It creates two message-text-wrapper and another one wraps everything.

Comment: @TimRodham, Apparently, I'm not getting it. I've removed my -1 and my comments.

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery's `wrapAll()` function](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$('.message-text').wrapAll("<div class='message-text-wrapper' />");
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/euEKk/).

**Edit:**

Per your instructions in the comments, the code below will wrap each individual element in the div. The fiddle has been updated as well.

```
$('.message-text').wrap("<div class='message-text-wrapper' />");
```

Comment: Yes, I actually tried this before but that wraps all inside one wrapper. In the output what I would like to have is multiple different wrappers.

Comment: @user995317, I misunderstood the requirements. See above edit.